# How to decide in what hour event starts in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

if i'm trying to create an event in this page :

[image: event_shecduler]

Now i have set it to run every 1 month, but how do i set at what time?
i want the report to save all record from last month into a table using

```
l.created_on <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 month)
```

So it will run at `1/1/12 00:00:00` i guess but i'd rather wait 2 minutes just in case something was inserted in the exact same moment, so i can i set that **while using phpMyAdmin**?

Comment: Did you try and edit the cron entry manually?

Comment: No i havn't i wanted to use phpMyAdmin since i'm not really an sql expert...

Comment: Recurring jobs are run by cron - it doesn't require you to be a SQL expert. Just check the cron entires created by phpmyadmin. Use your control panel software or execute `crontab -e` as the user running Apache to see what entries are written. There you can modify it to be hourly/minute, etc.

Comment: Yo see a lil calendar icon, that's where you set

Comment: @Mr.Alien Isn't that to set at what date to start doing the event and to what date stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I meant was set the time here... That's a common trigger for date as well as time

[image: MySQL cron job]

Comment: So would that mean that the reccuring will act as 1 month exactly from the time i set at start? if ya then thank you.

Comment: @eric.itzhak obviously, I've never used a cron before but it doesn't make any sense if it doesn't respect the time you've set...

Comment: Ya i get that i just assumed this is for setting the period of time this event is valid.

Comment: @Mr.Alien how can i debug event permonth it came from my [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400140/auto-add-field-each-user-using-event-nothing-error-and-doesnt-working)