# auto add field each user using event nothing error and doesn't working

Tags: events, schedule

well i'm not familiar using event in phpmyadmin, so this is new for me been searching 2 days without results then quit cause weekend.

this is my screen shoot doing event 
[image]

i have been testing by change date in local computer but nothing happend, then i decide to test simple event with this bellow event it working good,
[image]

my question is why my first event doesn't working, Thanks

Comment: Is your MySQL server running on your local machine or a remote host/other computer on your LAN? Based on what I'm reading above, my guess is that it's not your local computer, so when you change your local date/time, it isn't affecting the MySQL server, so your event doesn't run as expected.

Comment: MySQL server still running in my local machine, what do i wrong in here all instruction in stackoverflow  and google already follow but nothing happen been stuck in this issue 4 days do i stupid ?

Comment: I don't have a definite answer, but it seems to me that MySQL doesn't like when you change the system date. Try changing your event to 1 hour (or 5 minutes or whatever) for testing purposes, better to adjust the interval than the system date; once you know it works set it for the desired interval and start date. You can also try running that SQL code manually to verify whether it has the desired effect.

Comment: so your suggest to me just testing with sort time let say just 5 minutes, if it work only 5 minutes it also work for one month, is it ?

Comment: hi @IsaacBennetch yes it run for 5 minutes, what should i do ? i need to make sure it working ? sorry to much asking

Comment: I think that's what Isaac suggests - if it will work with 5 minutes schedule, it will work with 1 month schedule as well. Just remember to keep event scheduler enabled.

Comment: Exactly. I'd try with a shorter interval to make sure everything works correctly then adjust the interval to once per month. Then you can make a note in your calendar and wait to see what happens. As Michal said, if it works with a five minute interval it should also work with a one month interval.

Comment: hi @IsaacBennetch so there is no testing for month just make sure it work ?

Comment: Your options are a bit limited; at this point you've tested the code itself, you've tested that the event scheduler is actually active, and you've tested that your event runs properly with the five-minute interval. For me, the next logical step is to set up the month-long interval and wait to see. I suppose you may have luck by stopping the MySQL daemon, changing your machine time to a good margin before the scheduled monthly event (perhaps five minutes or so prior), then starting the MySQL daemon again. This should trick MySQL in to changing the time, I suppose, but your results may vary.